R data.table - replace cells in a loop
There is an inconsistency in the following loop with data.table.
While print( DT[ 2, ..i ] ) produces no error message, DT[ 2, ..i ] <- 45 does.
Conversely, print( DT[ 2, i ] ) produces an error message, but DT[ 2, i ] <- 45 works well.
Does somebody has an explanation for this inconsistency? How to code this loop correctly ?
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15)
DT
for( i in 1:3){
  print( DT[ 2, ..i ] )
 # print( DT[ 2, i ] ) 
 # DT[ 2, ..i ] <- 45
  DT[ 2, i ] <- 45
}


I am aware that the loop is not useful in this example, but I am especially interested in the loop in my application.

You are not supposed to use <- for sub-assignment with data.tables. Use :=.
DT[2, (1:3) := 45]

You should study help(":=", "data.table").

Or if they really need to use the loop: for(i in 1:3) DT[ 2, (i) := 45 ]

@zx8754 In a loop, I would prefer for(i in 1:3) set(DT, 2L, i, 45L).
